# How to calculate the Fourier coefficients for the function $x \mapsto x \cos(x)$ in the interval $]-\pi, \pi[$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the function $f \in C_{st}$ which on the interval $]-\pi, \pi[$ is equal to the function $x \cos(x)$. Then I have to find the Fourier coefficients $c_{-1}, c_0, c_1$. I know that the Fourier coefficients are defined as
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x \cos(x) e^{-inx} dx
$$
and that to calculate $c_1$ for an example I know that I just have to substitute $n=1$ and then calculate the integral but it is a real struggle for me. Do you mind helping me calculating $c_1$ so I can see how to approach questions like this? I know that $c_0 = 0$ as $x \cos(x)$ is an ueven function.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could just use $e^{-inx}=\cos(-nx)+i\sin(-nx)$ and integrate by parts.

Comment: You can write $cos(x) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ and combine with the $e^{-inx}$ if that helps with the integration by parts.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind verifying if my solution is correct? We have that: \begin{align*} c_1 & = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} x \cos(x) e^{-ix} dx \\ & = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x(1-e^{-2ix} dx \\ & = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \left( \left[x(x-\frac{1}{2}ie^{-2ix}) \right]_{x=-\pi}^{\pi} - \left[x-\frac{1}{2}ie^{-2ix} \right]_{x=-\pi}^{\pi} \right)  \\
& = \frac{1}{4\pi} \left( \pi(\pi - \frac{1}{2}ie^{-2i\pi}) + \pi (-\pi - \frac{1}{2}ie^{2\pi}) \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \left( \pi^2 - \frac{1}{2}i\pi - \pi^2 - \frac{1}{2}i\pi \right) \\
& = -\frac{i}{4}
\end{align*}

Comment: I see there is a mistake in line three at the last integral which I thought was $0$ but is actually $2 \pi$ which doesn't give the right result. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than express this in exponential form, express it in trigonometric form:

$\displaystyle b_n = \frac 1 \pi \int_0^\pi x \cos x \sin n x \mathrm d x$

which you can do because it is odd. This is then the half range Fourier sine series.

I will leave it to you to do the work.